# Adding custom font on iphone

Tags: iphone

Hi can someone give me a detail explanation on how to add custom font on iphone labels?

I have already created a key on info.plist

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
        <string>custom.ttf</string>
</array>
```

But don't know whats the next step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All custom font on iphone(development) should be added on app info.plist

Add row

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
        <string>custom.ttf</string>
</array>
```

**Then add the custom.ttf to the project.**

Create a subclass of the UILabel

```
@interface CustomLabel : UILabel {

}

@end

@implementation CustomLabel

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder: decoder]) {
        UIColor *textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.20f green:0.20f blue:0.20f alpha:1.0f];
        [self setTextColor:textColor];
        [self setShadowColor:textColor];
        [self setHighlightedTextColor:textColor];
        [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"custom" size:self.font.pointSize]];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Thats it, you are ready for the custom font on your label.

**Note:**

For every labels you add on the app that you want to have a custom font, change the class identity to CustomLabel(name of the subclass UILabel).

Comment: I have similar kind of issue. I have used custom font. As normal font works fine but when there is special characters then font is not working.. Can you please help me