# How to set font style for table view cell (navigation based app) in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

Please help me. How to set different font styles (stylish sentences in table view cell) programmatically for table view cell???

Answer (score 15):

You can follow this guide for adding custom fonts on your app.

[Adding custom font on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922002/adding-custom-font-on-iphone/10922060#10922060)

Then you can call this code to set the font and font size

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"custom" size:12.0f]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set it with the help of UIFont see this code -

```
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:15.0];
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=2;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation;
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

here are many property of UITableViewCell who changes it look.
You can also set a UILabel on UITableViewCell like this -

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblView];
//lblView is your UILabel you can set its UIFont whatever you want
```

Thank You!!

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me some font styles like 'Custom', 'Arial'....or you can give me link of that where I can get a list and use whatever I need. Thanks a lot......

Comment: go to you XIB file , take a UILabel object select it and go to its Attribute inspector (it is just right side of window), now see its Font property - click on T - choose custom - now you will see there are so many font name which objective supports...

Comment: @dhanjit - Please accept the answer if it helped you. You accepting rate is 0% ... Not good :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a standard [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there's a ["`textLabel`" property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/textLabel) that you can access and set the font & size of (which you would do via UILabel's [`font`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/font) property).

Answer (score 0):

Starting in iOS 4, its possible to use custom fonts. This post shows how to include them into your project and how to set them on your views: http://blog.beefyapps.com/2010/06/custom-fonts-in-ios-4/

Answer (score 0):

you can add the font in the following way

```
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arail" size:12.0f];
```

OR

Give the font name as you want

```
      cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFontNameHere" size:12.0f];
```